# Is there a word for "unable to communicate with"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in if you learn a language, then you're now able to speak with someone that you otherwise wouldn't be able to communicate with.

I'm writing a paper and that word as an adjective would be very useful. Using that whole phrase sounds clunky in an already lengthy sentence. Thanks!

Comment: If you learn a language, you can speak with people you otherwise couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to use *unintelligible*. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/unintelligible) defines it:

> Impossible to understand.

So you could say

> I'm now able to speak with someone I was previously unintelligble to.

(I wanted to suggest *influent* (as the opposite of fluent), but apparently that does not mean what I think it means.)

Answer (score -1):

[**"inarticulate"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inarticulate) can be used when A isn't able to express their thoughts or ideas but understands perfectly what they are told.

> - "incapable of giving coherent, clear, or effective expression to one's ideas or feelings"